# Is there a way to select from a table name as per a parameter set without IF statement?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a scenario where one of the "ID"s decide what tables to use.

```
Eg: If ID = **1** 
    Then use EE**1**TimeHour and EE**1**TimeOff
    If ID = **2** 
      Then use EE**2**TimeHour and EE**2**TimeOff
```

There are currently 4 IDs and the proc is quite long and the only difference is the name of the tables.

The reason I don't want to use an If statement (if possible to skip) is because the rest of the code is repetitive. Just the difference in table names could be a wrong design decision but I was not the one who designed it. 
I tried using below code in dynamic SQL but it gave error:

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 159
>   Incorrect syntax near tablename"

(as I am assuming it doesn't allow it).

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @ID = ID from table a

SELECT @SQL = 'select T.* from EE' + CAST(@ID as NVARCHAR(1)) + 'TimeHour T'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: That error is impossible from the code you posted.

Comment: FWIW, that code seems fine for the purpose of what you're trying to achieve, so there's probably an error occurring somewhere else (possibly as a result of something you altered). As there error states, somewhere in your query is the word "tablename" and there's incorrect syntax near that...

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional variable and just concat your TableString + TableId into that variable.

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @ID = ID from table a

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max) = CONCAT('EE', @ID, 'TimeHour')

SELECT @SQL = 'select * from @TableName
```

When all done you need to perform an

```
exec (@sql)
```

In order to have it consume the variable for a table name.

As an example I ran this on my own database:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100) = '[Database].[dbo].[Table]'

DECLARE @Statement varchar(200) = 'Select Top 100 * FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC (@Statement)
```

And got desired results.

Comment: There isn't a syntax error but am unable to select from that it since its a variable.

Comment: Remove your alias 'T' and make sure your SELECT is written like so:  'Select Top 1 * From ' + @TableName     Then the EXEC(@SQL) will work

Comment: You have to take the variable out of the single quotes, or use the Concat function to build your sql.  You can still use your alias for more complex statements, you just have to build the string correctly.